# facebook app approval for on-premise product

Tags: facebook

We have an enterprise product that is deployed on-premise for each of our enterprise customers. One of the features of the product is that it allows facebook logins to publish community awareness messages to their public pages. We do this integration using an approved facebook app (with approval for publish_pages). Now, the problem we are facing is the following:

- The facebook app gets approved for only a single URL/domain name.
- The on-premise deployments are the deployments of the same product but as a separate instance in a different domain
- Therefore, for each instance, we have to use a different facebook app and get the app approved by the facebook team even though there is no difference in the facebook integration functionality.

My question is the following:

- Is there a way to avoid creating and approving multiple apps for the same feature just because they are a separate instance in a different domain ?

Comment: No, the basic rule of thumb is one app == one domain. You could decide on one “main” domain for all apps, and then handle login via that domain only. (But then you won’t be able to use the JS SDK any more on the other domains.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, from what you describe, would it be correct to assume that there is no universal approval for an app and needs to be approved for each domain where it is deployed ?

Comment: No, the app is reviewed, not the domain it is (currently) running on. You can change the domain your app is set up for at any time. But if you use multiple apps (meaning multiple apps created in the FB developer section, and therefor multiple app ids), you would need to get each single one approved separately, even if they share a code base and do exactly the same thing.